# Angular 2 only render using arrow function

Tags: angular

Angular 2 it's only rendering using arrw function, or am i doing something wrong?

```
this.service.getData(o).subscribe(res => {
  this.data = res.data
  this.view = res.view
});
```

Actually render my component, but

```
this.service.getData(o).subscribe(function(res){
  this.data = res.data
  this.view = res.view
});
```

Not error, but my component is not updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you're losing `context`:

```
let self = this;

this.service.getData(o).subscribe(function(res){
  self.data = res.data
  self.view = res.view
});
```

the subscribe take an `observer` object. so `this` in your code mean: context of `observer` object.

or using this method:

```
this.service.getData(o).subscribe((function(res){
  this.data = res.data
  this.view = res.view
}).bind(this));
```